# How to scan entire classpath for components in Spring ignoring base package?

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to create a pluggable system - add a dependency in your pom and you'll get a plugin in plugins list.

I provide a common interface for plgins.

```
public interface Plugin {
    public doSmt();
}
```

Then I override BeanPostProcessor where I look for beans implementing Plugin interface and register them in Plugins List Singleton for further usage.

```
@Override
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object o, String s) throws BeansException {
    return o;
}

@Override
public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object o, String s) throws BeansException {
    if (o instanceof Plugin){
        pluginContainer.getPlugins().put(s, (Plugin) o);
    }
    return o;
}
```

If all plugins are in the same base package, e.g. ru.mycompany.plugins, then I can configure spring context as follows and it will work fine:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="ru.mycompany.plugins">
    <context:include-filter type="assignable" expression="ru.mycompany.plugins.Plugin"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

But the problem is that in the future external plugins can appear. An they will have another packages. E.g. com.notmycompany.foo.bar.
So I need to scan entire classpath from the root (classpath*:**) to look for plugins.

How can I do that? Base-package attribute is mandatory, setting it as "*" or "**" won't work.

Perhaps I should override ConnectorsContainerPostProcessor to change components lookup implementation? I tried to do that but only constructor and setResourceLoader methods are invoked while the application loads the context.

How can I scan whole classpath with any package to be able to process beans in BeanPostProcessor?

Comment: Scanning the whole classpath isn't the smartest thing to do as it will take a long time and your application will take forever to startup. You might want to take a look at the [Spring Plugin](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-plugin) project or use a simply [java service provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) implementation instead of scanning the whole classpath. That is the same mechanism as used by the JRE to load JDBC drivers for instance and the same mechanism used by hibernate to detect Envers (amongst others).

Comment: I tried to add all known base packages and it took milliseconds to boot the app. 
I dug a little bit and discovered that WebApp classloader that is used doesn't return all loaded packages if I try to get resources using wildcard expression like "**". But it returns jars sources if I just pass "ru/" or "com/" to getResources(String). 
I think I'll try to override the classloader and use my own.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can specify for all packages or even is it smart way to do it. This will work but you need to define every package separately.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="ru.mycompany, com">
    <context:include-filter type="assignable" expression="ru.mycompany.plugins.Plugin"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

It will recursively scan all classes inside ru.mycompany.* and com.* package.

Comment: That is why I'm trying to find a way to override a lookup implementation.